# getline(cin,s1) not prompting me for input

Tags: c++

The getline(cin, s1) function is not prompting me to input a string. it appears as if it is being skipped over even when the if condition is being met. any help? code is below. the problem is in the first if statement.

//Exercise 3.2

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(){
char a1;

 cout << "Read line (L) or word (W)?:";
cin >> a1;

if (a1 == 'l'){
    string s1;
    getline(cin, s1);
    cout << s1 << endl;
}
else{
    string s1;
    while (cin >> s1){
        cout << s1 << endl;
    }
}
system("pause");
 return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
cin >> some_char_variable;
```

it reads the `char` and leaves the input stream pointer pointing at the next character, which is invariably the newline you entered.

If you then do a `getline()`, it will get the line, which is delineated by that newline in the input stream that you left there.

This is the same problem as when you mix `getchar()` and `fgets()` in C, the combination of which generally always confuses newcomers.

I tend to avoid mixing the two styles, such as by using `getline()` everywhere, such as with:

```
string choice;
getline(cin, choice);

if (choice[0] == 'l') ...
```

But, if you must mix them, you can clear out the line before trying to accept more data, with something like:

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Comment: so what would be the correct way to code the IF statement in order to properly get prompted by the input stream?